# Change Date format in ASCX file

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime

I have a custom list object and I am binding it to a repeater like this

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="Repeater1">
<ItemTemplate>
    <p><input type="text" class="datepicker2" name="txtEndDate" value="<%#Eval(" EndDate").ToString().Replace("T00:00:00", "") %>" /></p>
</ItemTemplate>
```

Note: Repeater data-binding is done correctly on back end. 
Now the date that comes from back end is in this format `2012-01-01`,I want repeater to show  this in `2012/01/01` this format. IS there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try to use `.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd")` try this code hope it will help.

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="Repeater1">
<ItemTemplate>
 <p><input type="text" class="datepicker2" name="txtEndDate" value="<%#(Convert.ToDateTime((Eval("EndDate"))).ToString(yyyy/MM/dd,CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) %>" /></p>
</ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: Error: No overload for method 'ToString' takes 1 arguments

Comment: You need to cast it to DateTime first:

Comment: `Remove()` is not needed now because you will get you `Date` in this format `yyyy/MM/dd` only

Comment: Your current code works except date format is not changing, its still 2012-01-01

Comment: i think your `Culturevarient` is different. please use this `ToString(yyyy/MM/dd,CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)`

Comment: or alternatively you can hard code it using `ToString("dd'/'MM'/'yyyy")`

Comment: Yes Now that worked(Culturevarient ), You can update your answer and i will accept it

Answer (score 0):

You have to cast it in datetime and then apply tostring with date format as below

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="Repeater1">
<ItemTemplate>
     <p><input type="text" class="datepicker2" name="txtEndDate" value="<%#Convert.ToDateTime(Eval("EndDate")).ToString("yyyy/MM/dd") %>" /></p>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```